# Typedef evaluation in a class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, typedef

Following code compiles with g++, but fails to compile with clang.

```
struct X;

template <typename T>
struct Traits
{
    typedef typename Traits<T>::Container Container;
};

template <>
struct Traits<X>
{
    typedef std::vector<X *> Container;
};

int main()
{
    Traits<X>::Container container;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

clang error message:

```
main.cpp:9:30: error: no type named 'Container' in 'Traits<T>'
```

Should compiler evaluate the typedef without substituting the template parameter with the actual type? Which compiler is right?

clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fef7725827074e4f

gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79e17031fcabcd83

Comment: `typedef typename Traits<T>::Container Container;` is an infinitely recursive typedef...

Comment: I would imagine that since Traits<T> is a dependent name, it should be evaluated during instantiation. But I can't prove it with any relevant Standard quote.

Comment: @cdhowie, I am not sure if it is, and even it would, compiler would probably  complain about max template depth, rather than of missing type?

Comment: @SergeyA It is. Yes, the error would be different. I'm not saying this is his problem, just pointing it out (hence comment rather than answer).

Comment: @cdhowie, why is it recursive? I do not see recursion here. Traits<T> is the name of the template itself, it is the same as the class being currently instantiated.

Comment: @SergeyA The typedef `Traits<T>::Container` is *defined* as being a typedef to `Traits<T>::Container`. How is that *not* recursive? Note that clang complains on this exact line, *without the rest of the program.* I'm wondering if the recursion actually isn't the problem after all! (Note that the specialization *isn't* recursive. But if you tried to refer to the non-specialized `Traits<T>::Container`, it would be recursive. It seems that clang might be trying to be a bit too smart here?)

Comment: @cdhowie, yep, specialization is not recursive, and it is the only thing which is used in the program. And non-specialized version is never instantiated and as such should not be recursive as well. I should have articulated my point better. And I am not sure if clang actions are justified.

Comment: @SergeyA Yeah, it's a bit weird. It sounds like we are in agreement but were using different words. :) The non-specialized template's typedef recurses but the specialized one does not, and it's a bit weird that clang is complaining before the non-specialized template even gets instantiated. I, too, am curious what the standard says about this case.

Comment: I guess, since both template versions are suitable for use, both are instantiated to finally check which is the best one. I am almost convinced that the compiler tries to instantiate the non-specialized template first, although it is not explicitly used. And failing there already, due to the recursion, it won't instantiate the specialization... Does anyone know a reference to the standard on instantiation behaviour, out of mind?

Answer (score 5):

```
template <typename T>
struct Traits {
  typedef typename Traits<T>::Container Container;
};
```

this is ill formed, no diagnostic required.  There is no `T` such that the above (primary) specialization could result in valid code.

The existence of another specialization makes no difference.  The compiler is free to do anything, including giving a spurious error message.  It is free to compile it.  It is free to generate an error only if you have a variable named `foo` elsewhere in the program, or if the moon is new.  Some if these are poor quality of implementation.

In practice, this means the compiler is free to assume the primary specialization is valid for some type `T` (i.e., does not have infinite recursion in it), and crap out in relatively unrelated code because it made that assumption.